# Search engine indexing - jQuery load triggered by onClick event

Tags: jquery, search, onclick

I have the following navigation links on my website.  I am wondering if search engines will crawl the links contained in onclick events.

```
<nav>
<a class="menu" href="#code" onclick="$('#content').load('code.php')">code</a> |
<a class="menu" href="#portfolio" onclick="$('#content').load('portfolio.php')">portfolio</a> |
<a class="menu" href="#about" onclick="$('#content').load('about.php')">about</a> | 
<a class="menu" href="#contact" onclick="$('#content').load('contact.php')">contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Probably not. Probably best to make said links available statically via the href attribute, then scrap onclick attributes and use a js include to parse out the target page and load it.

Comment: Even if google did index it, what url would it return to get to the content? If anything it would return the overall url which would go to the default page rather than the page the user is searching for.

Answer (score 0):

For Google, yes! They check also the onclick event and try to resolve it.
But im not sure, if it would work if you try to load it per ajax...
Here is a article about that:

http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/onclick.html

Hope it helps!